# Search within PDF files in Windows search

Tags: windows-7, pdf, search

We have files on a server (*just a plain Win7 server*), when you search with different computers in the same folder, some computer find a result (*that is within a PDF, in the text I mean*) while others don't find anything.

I have check on all the computers in "Folder Options →  Search →  Search within files", and also installed that PDF iFilter thing but still it works on a few computer and others not.
See images for example from 2 different computers:

[image: result]

[image: no result]

What could be the problem / solutions ?
Thanks for your help.

edit: maybe not unimportant, it WAS working on that computer that is now not working anymore. Maybe an Acrobat update or something caused the bug now ?

Comment: Upgrade to Windows 10, the search looks for terms inside PDF files.

Comment: I'm 99% sure the problem started since some computers switched from win7 to win10, so thanks but no thanks to upgrade again to Win10

Comment: Anyone please ?

Answer (score 3):

(DO NOT INDEX ENCRYPTION. THIS METHOD WORKS FOR WIN 7 64 BIT)

Under no circumstance enable indexing of encryption. (Indexing Encryption will allow anyone who uses your computer to get passwords and personal information. Plus it can screw up the OS!)

1. Go to Indexing > Advanced > File Types, and remove the check for PDF. Press OK > Press Close
2. Uninstall any Ifilters that you have relating to searching PDF Files
3. Unless you have Adobe Reader 9.3 or higher, uninstall it.
4. Go to Adobe.com and install Adobe Reader 9.3 or Higher if not already installed.
5. Download and install Ifilter 9 from Adobe (Win 7 64 bit only)  http://www.adobe.com/support/downloads/detail.jsp?ftpID=4025
6. Go back to Indexing > Advanced > File Types, and re-check PDF.  The Press the 'Index Settings Tab' (THEN WAIT)
7. Try and keep all your PDF files in one folder.
8. Search for a PDF in the Windows search box (top right). You should see a message prompt near the top of the screen telling you that indexing is turned off, then asks you if you want to turn it on. Click the message and click to enable indexing.
9. Go back to Indexing, and click Rebuild (The rebuilding will take hours and will not work until it is done!)

If you did as I said above, you will be able to click on a start button and search for PDF files, and the contents inside them, including ones that you may have used OCR.

Comment: Hello Dale,
I will try this afternoon thank you. That indexing & rebuild, this has to be done on the server computer (where the PDFs are stored) I guess ?
All that Reader installing thing has to be done on the client computers ?

Comment: So I tried it down. I copied a folder with a bunch of PDF files local, and it seems like on all the computers with 64bit, I can search within the PDF files. But on 32bit systems it's not working. Probably due to the iFilter setup ? (which one should I try for 32bit ?)

Answer (score 0):

The instructions from @Dale worked for me for Windows 2010, with these exceptions/notes:

- Used PDF iFilter 64 11.0.01 (http://supportdownloads.adobe.com/detail.jsp?ftpID=5542)
- I'm running Acrobat Professional Version X (10)
- It took four hours to rebuild the index of 39,000 items.