# Searching inside PDFs using the BuiltIn Windows search - Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, pdf, file-search

This is one of the few moments I miss MacOS.

Background - I have an archive of several thousand research papers that are saved as PDFs. To be able to find things I need a working search function. When I first setup this computer I installed the TET PDF IFilter: https://www.pdflib.com/download/tet-pdf-ifilter/ and for a while it worked.

2 yrs later something stopped working. I tried switching to the Adobe iFilter. No luck. If we look inside my search settings:
[image: Search Settings]

As you can see PDFs are indexed using the PDF filter

Using Windows 10 (Build 19042). The iFilter I have installed is the Adobe on. My PDF reader is FoxIt (although I can't see how that interferes.)

I have seen: [Search within PDF files in Windows search](https://superuser.com/questions/1096614/search-within-pdf-files-in-windows-search) and I've taken most of those steps several times over.

*Bizarre followup - After some spelunking and playing - search via the Windows taskbar does appear to search inside any files (PDF, Powerpoint, Word etc). Search from within Windows File Explorer does all of this. I'm  more confused than when I started.

I discovered this via: https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/all/windows-10-wont-search-file-contents/a91339ff-34f3-448e-a131-e401a3e0c31f*

Comment: For a similar situation (searching inside PDF files) I use command-line tool [RipGrep-All](https://github.com/phiresky/ripgrep-all). First, I install [Chocolatey](https://chocolatey.org/) Windows package manager and then ripgrep-all with `choco install`. It pulls all the needed dependancies. It is the only supported solution for Windows by the ripgrep-all devs. Otherwise I would use the Ubuntu package under WSL2.

Comment: Try to reset index to check https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/58569-rebuild-search-index-windows-10-a.html, if issue persists, try to update Windows in settings\Update & Security and restart computer to check.

Comment: I have reset the index about 100 times in this agonizing process.

Comment: I tested on my side with Windows 10 version 2004 with default settings, it works well with index in PDF contents and tittle. Try to reset index with those all of those measures. https://winbuzzer.com/2020/09/25/how-to-reset-and-rebuild-the-search-index-in-windows-10-xcxwbt/ If it not works well, we could consider to reset PC though settings\Update & Security\recovery. You could choose keep your personal data.

Answer (score 2):

In your screen shot for PDF, look at the options below. Change from Index properties only to the one below: Index including file contents. Then if the PDF was scanned as Searchable, Search will find it.

You will likely have to rebuild your index. Let the rebuild occur overnight.

Here is a screen shot showing the Adobe Content requirement. This should be set.  I hope this helps.

[image]

Comment: That is what it is already set to. I have also done the rebuild several times.

Comment: The screen shot shows just properties, not the Content also setting, so that is why i posted.

Comment: I added a screen shot to assist.

Comment: I understood the ref. When my original screen shot was taken I didn't have PDF selected. I don't which file was selected. ..... If it windows only thinks it is searching the file then it says "File Properties Filter". Instead it says "PDF Filter" presumably the name of Adobe TET Filter.